# cannot do pass by reference for a boolean variable in android

Tags: java, android, touch-event, pass-by-value

I am upto the touchevent listner where it records the touch and i have used viewpager for swping.. as we know drawback of java is pass by value thing, I m still trying to pass the boolean value inside the anonymous inner class. The value changed in the switch stmt is not persisting outside the switch stmt. The flag2 value .anyone have solution for this? my code is as below

```
 parent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //flag2=!flag2;
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                        awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        //flag2=false;
                        break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                     if(flag)
                     {
                       upperdock.setClickable(false);
                        upperdock.bringToFront();
                        tocparent.bringToFront();
                        tocbottom.bringToFront();
                        upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                        tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                        tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                        flag=false;
                    // obj.one(event.getAction());
                     }
                     else
                 {

                        parent.bringToFront();
                        upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
                        tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                        tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                        flag=true;
                 //obj.one(event.getAction());
                     }


                    flag2=true;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    flag2=false;
                    break;


                }


            return flag2;

            }

        });
```

> ```
> public class SimpleViewPagerforAndroidActivity extends Activity {
> /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>  boolean flag2=true;
> //rest of the code
> }
> ```

Please help... need it..

```
package com.beanie.samples.viewpager;

       //set of imports

      public class SimpleViewPagerforAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


     volatile boolean flag2=true;




       AwesomePagerAdapter awe1;




         @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        cxt = this;
        data = new ArrayList<WebView>();

       awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        awesomePager.setAdapter(new AwesomePagerAdapter(this,data));

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

           Boolean dock2checked = extras.getBoolean("dock1");

           if(dock2checked)
           {
               Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Boolean.toString(dock2checked), 5000);
               toast1.show();
           }
           else
           {
               Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Boolean.toString(dock2checked), 5000);
               toast1.show();
           }







    awesomePager.setOffscreenPageLimit(11);

   //       
    web0 = new WebView(cxt);
    web0.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1/01-Cover.html");
  WebSettings webSettings0 = web0.getSettings();
  webSettings0.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web1 = new WebView(cxt);
    web1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1/01-Cover.html");
  WebSettings webSettings1 = web1.getSettings();
  webSettings1.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web2 = new WebView(cxt);
    web2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/5/05-01.html");
    WebSettings webSettings2 = web2.getSettings();
      webSettings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

     web3 = new WebView(cxt);
    web3.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1/01-Cover.html");
    WebSettings webSettings3 = web3.getSettings();
      webSettings3.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web4 = new WebView(cxt);
    web4.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/5/05-01.html");
    WebSettings webSettings4 = web4.getSettings();
      webSettings4.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web5 = new WebView(cxt);
    web5.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1/01-Cover.html");
    WebSettings webSettings5 = web5.getSettings();
      webSettings5.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web6 = new WebView(cxt);
    web6.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/5/05-01.html");
    WebSettings webSettings6 = web6.getSettings();
      webSettings6.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web7 = new WebView(cxt);
    web7.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1/01-Cover.html");
    WebSettings webSettings7 = web7.getSettings();
      webSettings7.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web8 = new WebView(cxt);
    web8.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/5/05-01.html");
    WebSettings webSettings8 = web8.getSettings();
      webSettings8.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web9 = new WebView(cxt);
    web9.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1/01-Cover.html");
    WebSettings webSettings9 = web9.getSettings();
      webSettings9.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web10 = new WebView(cxt);
    web10.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/5/05-01.html");
    WebSettings webSettings10 = web10.getSettings();
      webSettings10.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



    data.add(web0);
    data.add(web1);
    data.add(web2);
    data.add(web3);
    data.add(web4);
    data.add(web5);
    data.add(web6);
    data.add(web7);
    data.add(web8);
    data.add(web9);
    data.add(web10);





      tocparent=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tocparent);
      dock2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      //dock2.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
      tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);

      topmost=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.topmost);
      parent=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
        upperdock=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.upperdock);
        tocparent=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tocparent);
        tocbottom=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);
        upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);







      web0.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf()");




parent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //flag2=!flag2;
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                        awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        //flag2=false;
                        break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                     if(flag)
                     {
                       upperdock.setClickable(false);
                        upperdock.bringToFront();
                        tocparent.bringToFront();
                        tocbottom.bringToFront();
                        upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                        tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                        tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                        flag=false;
                    // obj.one(event.getAction());
                     }
                     else
                 {

                        parent.bringToFront();
                        upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
                        tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                        tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                        flag=true;
                 //obj.one(event.getAction());
                     }
                    flag2=true;


                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                    flag2=false;
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, 220).show();
                     //obj.one(event.getAction());
                    break;


                }
      /*  if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            flag2=true;
        }
        else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        {
            flag2=false;
        }*/

            return flag2;

            }

        });








      awesomePager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

           public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
               //Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "PageSelected"+ arg0, 5000);
                //Toast1.show();
            if(arg0==0)
            {
            //web0.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf()");

    //              awesomePager.getChildAt(arg0 - 1);
                web0.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf1()");
                web0.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf()");

            }
            else if(arg0==1)
            {
                web1.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf1()");
                web1.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf()");


            }

            else if(arg0==3)
            {

                web3.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf1()");
            //Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fun"+ arg0, 5000);
            //Toast2.show();
            }
            else if(arg0==5)
                web5.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf()");
            else if(arg0==7)
                web7.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf()");
            else if(arg0==9)
                web9.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf()");
           }

           public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

           }



           public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int o = awesomePager.getCurrentItem();
            WebView temp = (WebView) awesomePager.getChildAt(o); 

               if(arg0 == 1)
               {



                temp.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf1()");
               }

               else if(arg0 == 0)
               {

                   temp.loadUrl("javascript:fhhf()");
               }

           }
          });






}
 public boolean fun1()
   {
       return true;
   }
 public boolean fun2()
   {
       return false;
   }


private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter  implements           ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private List<WebView> data;
    private Context ctx1;

    public AwesomePagerAdapter(Context ctx, List<WebView> data) {
        this.ctx1 = ctx;
        this.data = data;
    }







    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {



        data.get(position).setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
        return data.get(position);

      }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {

            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((WebView) view);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {



            return view==((WebView)object);

    }



    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
    }


    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}



    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {


    }



    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    }


 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which value is not getting changed?

Comment: flag2 value.. it is globally declared as true in the class

Comment: What anonymous inner class? You don't post one. However, a non-static anonymous inner class should be able to change the value of fields in the class but not method-scope variables unless they are final (which won't help you change the value of a boolean).

Comment: If you want to pass by reference a primitive variable like `boolean`, you must usa a wrapper object lile `Boolean`...

Comment: You can't do pass by reference for *anything* in Java.

Comment: @John B.. i have edited my code.. see now..

Comment: @davioooh have tried with Boolean too it even dint work.

Comment: Please include where / how `flag` is declared.

Comment: @JohnB have included that too in my code.. do help is there anyway?

Comment: Try making it `volatile`. It is being accessed from multiple threads so you need to have thread-safety around it. From what thread is it being read? You might want to consider posting the entire class at this point. Let's see how it is being set and how it is being read. But first try the `volatile`.

Comment: @droids this ontouch listener is in other class?

Comment: volatile too doesnt work @JohnB

Comment: Then you are going to have to give us more code

Comment: @JohnB have posted whole code

Comment: @can come to chat and explain there not getting what u want come at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11936/android-lite

Comment: In your code, I do not see where `flag2` is being used outside the OIC. So what do you mean that it is not being set? How do you know if you are not reading it?

Comment: @davioooh: `Boolean` won't work. wrapper types (which are immutable reference types) are basically semantically equivalent to their primitive counterparts -- in both cases, assignment is the only way to change them

Comment: Why dont you make it `public static boolean flag2` in declaration? and then access it everywhere like `ClassName.flag2 = true`

Answer (score 0):

first make a method in **SimpleViewPagerforAndroidActivity** as given below u can also either use **void** if u don't want to return anything

```
 boolean method(Boolean flag){
    flag2=flag;
    return flag2;
}
```

Make an **object** in other class  as shown below

**SimpleViewPagerforAndroidActivity** abc=new **SimpleViewPagerforAndroidActivity();**

and in ontouch event in **switch** statement call method  by

```
abc.method(false or true);
```

this will update ur **flag2** and u can check as by print in Log by

```
Log.d("flag2",""+abc.flag2);
```

Comment: i tried this too.. since object have reference type in java. but this too dint work.. Took a Boolean array and tried it.. that also dint work.. is there anything fixing both swiping by viewpager and touch effect  by touchListener both together.. i mean while swiping it must not take touchListener action?

Comment: i have check in log and got value true which is parfacr if not got than show ur whole code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try forcing it to run on the UI Thread?

IE:

```
public void passBoolean(final boolean boolToPass){      
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //Do whatever here on the UI thread
        }
    });    
}
```